# Building an api as a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am building an api for others to use. This is a simple enough Json request the user passes as some data and we pass some back.

What I would love is to secure our api and have some sort of user system where we can turn users on and off and we can log how many requests each user makes.

What would be the best way to do this in Rails? I don't want it to slow down the request. I can see ways of doing it using devise maybe but would be great to hear other people's opinions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before using the Token Authentication capabilities of devise (see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise ).

I found the following setup works:

- Create a user account for each api user.
- Configure devise for token authentication
- Set the Token Authentication configuration to require the token to be submitted with *each request*.

This will allow you to enable and disable individual users as well as to track every request back to the api user that made the call.

If you're really interested in tracking usage you may want to consider also creating a database table where you track all api requests. This can be setup to `belong_to` the users table so that you easily find all requests from different users (e.g., `@user.api_requests`).

The count of all requests made by a user would be:

```
@user.api_requests.count

# or use a where clause to find how many of each type
@user.api_requests.where("api_request_type = ?", 'SomeAPICallType').count
```

One final note -- I recently used the Grape library for building out an API. I thought it was pretty well done and it worked great for our needs. I especially like the ability it provided to version APIs. Details are here: https://github.com/intridea/grape/wiki

Comment: Thanks - I am a little worried about overheads - maybe pushing the logging into a background job might help?

Comment: I'd get it running first, then after that probably push it off to a job like you're saying. I'd likely use resque for the job processing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use 3scale (http://www.3scale.net) - it's free up to a traffic cap but handles all the key management, users, documentation etc. and there's a ruby library which you can drop into your code if you're using rails. (other libs are here: https://support.3scale.net/libraries).